# I'm trying to find the actor that appear the most in the cast in the Netflix Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on the Netflix dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shivamb/netflix-shows) and I'm trying to find the top 15 actor that appears the most in the column 'cast'.

My first problem is that actor are separate by a comma in each cells. I used the str.split function to create a new dataframe with 1 actor on each cell but I can't find a way to count the number of time each actor appears.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you

I tried to use str.split to get a new dataframe

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand what you got from your dataset, you have now a list with only the actors, in a certain order and a certain number of times.
You would like to turn that list to a dictionary, with the keys being the actors, and the values being the number of times they appear.

A simple way to achieve this is to use the `Counter` object from the `collections` module. A simple explanation is shows [here](https://realpython.com/python-counter/)